# Latex character error while splitting chapters

Tags: accents, input-encodings

I'm writing a LaTeX document and everything works fine, but as I try to split the document chapters in different `.tex` files, I receive several errors related to the characters in the document (and with the encoding, I suppose). In the document I use a lot of accented letters with direct insertion, such as `ì` or `è`. I used

```
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
```

to let this work and it do work as long as the chapter are all together in the main file. But as I try to copy the first chapter in a separate file and use `\input` or `\include` in the main file, I get a series of errors related to the characters.
Why does that happens?

Comment: What gives you the error: some latex processor ? which one ? or you editing environment / syntax checker ? And _please_ don't refer to errors without actually specifying them here.

Comment: You can use `\include` only at the top level. Any nesting of `\include` isn't allowed.

Comment: no I receive errors when I compile the .tex file, errors such as "Missing $ inserted" when it founds an "ì", or "Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined in inputencoding 'latin1'" when it founds "È", ecc...
The problem is that I do not get these errors if I just directly write the chapter content instead of using \input

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously the new files you are trying to input are not latin1 encoded. Probably you/your editor chose utf8 as encoding for them. Either reencode the file to latin1 or tell LaTeX that the files use another encoding by loading the utf8-definitions and adding `\inputencoding{utf8}` at the start of the file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8,latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}

\inputencoding{utf8}
\input{....} %utf8 encoded file 

\inputencoding{latin1} %back to latin1 

\end{document}
```

Comment: whoa, it worked just perfect! it seems like it was actually the problem! thanks a lot dude :D